# How to make bootstrap divs of same height

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know that this is a common asked question but I cannot figure out how to solve my situation.
I have a form with two divs inside a Tab and I would the divs have the same height.

Here the code: http://www.bootply.com/AgakDOBgH0#

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

a quick workaround is to set a fixed height for the column,

since you define styles inline change this selector (twice), for ex. 250px:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 padded_div" style="padding-right: 20px; height: 250px; background-color: red">
```